# Check if NSNumber has trailing .00 digits or not

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I have a method that creates a money style string from an NSNumber.

```
+ (NSString *)formatShortPayment: (NSNumber *)payment {

    if (![payment isEqual: [NSNull null]]) {

        // Set locale to GB
        NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setLocale: locale];
        [formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

        // If the payment is 1000 or over, get rid of fraction numbers
        if ([payment doubleValue] >= 1000.0) {
            [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits: 0];
            payment = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([payment floatValue] / 1000)];
        }

        else {
            // Here's where I want to check if the value ends with .00 or not
        }

        // Return clean number
        return [formatter stringFromNumber: payment];

    }

    return nil;
}
```

This works great, but if the value is < 1000.0 I'd like to check what the trailing digits are and remove them if they equal .00.

For example:
25.00 => 25
13.29 => 13.29

I'm not sure how best to accomplish this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if (([payment doubleValue] - floor([payment doubleValue]) < 0.01) {
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits: 0];
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Works elegantly and expected. Thank you.

Comment: Clever indeed. I wonder if this works for all currencies, but I'm guessing that there isn't any currency that has more than two fraction digits...

Comment: @ErikvanderNeut My country, and a few neighboring countries, do. Not that uncommon, so if you are looking to make something as international as possible, better avoid this. This simply answers the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks for that added info @Mazyod - In your specific case, are you talking about the AED (United Arab Emirates Dirham)? How many fraction digits do you use? Do you always use the same number, or is it okay to drop some?

Comment: @ErikvanderNeut I'm actually referring to my home country, KWD (Kuwait). We use 3 digits there. I believe Oman, Bahrain, and Libya use 3 digits, as well. AED, SR (Saudi), QR (Qatar) use 2 digits.